# Algorithm for converting Binary tree to post-fix mathematical expression?

Tags: algorithm

I have a Binary tree for  a mathematical expression(infix), i want to convert directly this TREE to a postfix(Stack)
can any body suggest the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re searching for is known as post-order [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-order_traversal):

```
postorder(node)
  if node.left  ≠ null then postorder(node.left)
  if node.right ≠ null then postorder(node.right)
  print node.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, each node is (Left, Right, Data).

Start with the first node. execute the algorithm for the left subtree if available and then execute the algorithm for the right subtree and then print the data.

```
TreeNode = ([TreeNode], Data, [TreeNode])

TreeToPostfix: [TreeNode] -> Data*
TreeToPostfix(nil) = []
TreeToPostfix((left, data, right)) ==
  TreeToPostfix(left) ++ TreeToPostfix(right) ++ Data
```

For example:

```
              +
            /   \
           *     -
          / \   / \
         2   3 4   5
```

Produces: 2 3 * 4 5 - +

Comment: can u plz explain the approach as data will always be at lowset level of tree

Comment: Data in this case is both value and operator. My algorithm prduced prefix, but is now fixed to postfix.